# Create File with FIXED BLOCK(FB) using FtpWebRequest

Tags: asp.net, ftp, mainframe, ftpwebrequest

I am Ftp'ing a file to mainframe, for the first time FtpWebRequest will create the file with VB(Variable Blocked) record format.

But I don't see any option to create a file with FB(Fixed Block).
My intension is to ask FtpWebRequest to do something like bellow.

```
QUOTE SITE RECFM=FB LRECL=500
```

Comment: What do you mean by "for the first time"? What have you coded? Have you looked at recent questions tagged mainframe and ftp? Why don't you pre-allocate the dataset on the Mainframe with the DCB information that you want?

Comment: I cant preallocate them..because every time its different name.. So wont be able to ask them creating a file before doing ftp..when i am following the general src and batch file approach to do ftp..that time its working fine. But using ftpWebRequest class.. I dont see any option to specify those properties.